# Calling non static method inside of main method

Tags: java

I am trying to call the `private Client()` inside of the `main` method but it is saying

> non static method Client can not be referenced from a static context.

```
public class Client extends JFrame 
{
    private Client() 
    {    
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/appIcon.png"));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        setSize(900, 450); 
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);  
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIconImage(icon.getImage());
        setVisible(true); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    }   
}
```

Comment: You *can* build a `Client` object inside your main method. I don't understand what you meant by "calling" `private Client()`, though.

Comment: @webuster: Probably just tried `Client()` rather than `new Client()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Client` is a constructor. You call it via `new`:

```
Client c = new Client();
```

You can do that inside `main`.

If it were an instance method, you'd need an instance to call it on. But because it's a constructor, you use it to *create* an instance (which you might then call instance methods on).

Comment: I tried that but I don't know what to do after that, sorry that i didn't include it in my first question.

Comment: @user3120013: Anything you want. The line above will create an instance and call your code in your constructor, which does things like set the size and such. When the constructor returns, `main` gets control back, and you can use `c` to do whatever else you want to do. `c` refers to an instance of your `Client` class, which is a subclass of `JFrame`. So anything you can do with a `JFrame`, you can do with `c`.